# SCSS changes don't seem to be taking effect in Jekyll site?

Tags: html, sass, jekyll, jekyll-theme, minima

I have a Github Pages site built with Jekyll. I'm using the [Minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) Jekyll theme.

I'm trying to apply custom styles to my classes, but no matter what I put, it's not taking effect. All the SCSS styles are under `_sass/minima`, mostly in the file `_layout.scss`.

The styles that come default in that file are taking effect. See the below screenshot:

[image]

But in this screenshot, the styles I defined (`doc-header`, `doc-nav`, and `doc-page-link`) are no where to be found, even though they're defined in the exact same file (`_layout.scss`):

[image]

The site comes with a `custom-styles.scss`, which is a

> Placeholder to allow defining custom styles that override everything else.

I tried putting the styles there, but no change.

Edit: I just tried editing the pre-built styles. I changed some text color to pink, but still nothing. So it seems like these files aren't even being processed at all?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24279476/22146392) that said to add front matter to the files, but I tried that and it still didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I assumed the [head](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/head.html) that points to the stylesheet would be automatically built in but I guess it isn't. Once I copied in the head.html from the minima repo into _includes it started working as expected.